# Mod_Rewrite recipe

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

I need to accomplish the following with mod_rewrite:

```
URI request: http://domain.com/user/username/ or http://domain.com/user/username
URI translate: http://domain.com/?q=user/username
```

This needs to be very specific, with no wildcards. Could an expert on mod_rewrite and regex lend a hand? Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to do this with no wildcards if "username" will be changing? Or is this for a specific username?

Comment: What I meant was, the ruleset needs to be as specific (strict) as possible as to not interfere with another. It needs to match /user/variableusername precisely. The "variableusername" will always be lowercase alphabetic.

Comment: I thought of something like: "RewriteRule ^user/[a-z]$  /?q=user/$1", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add answer seems to be broken, here is what I came up with: The best I could come up with is to create a /user/ directory and add this into it's .htaccess file:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   ^(\w+)  /?q=user/$1  [R,L]

I think there is a way to do this by putting .htaccess in the root web directory but I couldn't seem to make it work without getting into a loop.

The above script will trim out anything after a "username", for example if someone requested *http://domain.com/user/username/filename* it would still redirect to *http://domain.com/?q=user/username*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're forgetting the + after the [a-z]:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)$ /?q=user/$1 [L]
```

I tried on my server and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^user/[a-z]$        /?q=user/$1
```

But it doesn't work. [Dave Drager](https://serverfault.com/users/4271/dave-drager), I am looking for a cleaner version (not sure if your approach will work, but would rather not create a directory, want all from .htaccess).

Comment: I'm going crazy, It won't let me add an answer, says "page doesn't exist"! Try RewriteRule ^/user/(\w+) /?q=user/$1 [R,L]